# Return number of the row of the max date

Tags: excel

I want to return the number of the row when the max date  is "Jorge"

in this case i want return number "2" to use in another function

```
  ___A_______|__B_____  
1  21/04/2020   Jorge
2  05/05/2020   Jorge
3  15/06/2020   Pedro
```

Comment: Hi there, what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have access to the `MAXIFS` function, you can use the `MATCH` entered as an array formula:

```
=MATCH(MAX($A$1:$A$3*($B$1:$B$3="Jorge")),$A$1:$A$3*($B$1:$B$3="Jorge"),0)
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ahh you changed the question on me. Here is an answer for your updated question.

```
=MATCH(MAXIFS(A1:A3,B1:B3,"Jorge"),IF(B1:B3="Jorge",A1:A3),0)
```

CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER when you put this formula in.

Also, note that this will return the row in the selected data. You may need to use offset function or add an offset to the result if your data range does not start at 1 and you wish to get the absolute row number from the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE/MAXIFS

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:A3)/((A1:A3=MAXIFS(A:A,B:B,"Jorge"))*(B1:B3 = "Jorge"),1)
```